# PyQt: Replace white pixels in QImage (filter whitish pixels)

Tags: colors, pyqt, qimage

I'm looking for an efficient way to find all pixels that are "whitish" (all rgb channels are above some threshold). The image is in QImage object. Which is the best way in terms of processing time? I'm trying to avoid looping through all the pixels.
I've found that cv2 has function called `inRange` which sounds just right, but I found it hard to move back to QImage from numpy.array. Please help?

Comment: how can you avoid looping over them all, unless you had a pre-processing that indexed those that were whitish then you could just retrieve that index, or if the image gets edited in your app you could keep track of which pixels are whitish as the user is editing them (again via an index), but short of that I don't see a way of avoiding a loop. What do you want to do with the pixels found, this might change approach.

Comment: @Schollii, That's not correct. I've found a solution to this problem.
I used `mask = img > threshold`
This returns binary image with 3 channels. Then I did:
`new_mask = mask[:,:,0] & mask[:,:,1] & mask[:,:,2]` in order to get a binary value per pixel.
It worked great and a lot faster than going through every pixel in the image.

Comment: there is still a loop but it is at the C++/binary layer instead of the Python layer.... in fact, there are 3 or 4 loops. But since the binary layer is often 10 times as fast as the Python layer, you're still better off with the technique you used. Well done!